# model.set woking in the console but not in my actual script

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to set an attribute in each of the models of my collection but the code I am using is not working (attributes have not been updated), though it works when I run it directly into the console. Here is my code, the code in question is the questions.forEach...:

```
var Question = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "questions.json"
});

var Questions = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Question,

    url: "questions.json",

    parse: function(response){
       return response.questions;
    }
});

var questions = new Questions();
questions.fetch();

var questionOrder = [];

while (questionOrder.length != 10){
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    if (questionOrder.indexOf(randomNum) == -1) {
        questionOrder.push(randomNum);
    }
}

questions.forEach(function(model, i) {
    model.set({"order": questionOrder[i]});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the fetch is complete before trying to update the models.

Put the update function in a callback on the fetch.
(Make sure you set up questionOrder before calling fetch.)

```
questions.fetch(success: function() {
    questions.forEach(function(model, i) {
        model.set({"order": questionOrder[i]});
    })
;);
```

When running in the console you don't need to wait for the fetch.